# Switch between different ML models that run on camera in kotlin on runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, google-mlkit

I am trying to make an app that allow user to switch between different ML-Models on fly. Right now i have a simple app that can run camera with no model and camera with an object detection model. There will be five such models in final app.

This is my `Home Activity`

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(), EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
private val rqSpeechRec = 102
private var tts: TextToSpeech? = null
private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding
private lateinit var objectDetector: ObjectDetector
private lateinit var cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // Binding ViewData
    binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    supportActionBar?.hide() // Hiding App bar

    requestCameraPermission()   // Requesting Camera Permission
}
```

This is my `Request Camera Permission` function.

```
private fun requestCameraPermission() {
    speakOut("Allow Eynetic to access the camera to take photos or videos.")

    EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
        this,
        "This app can not work without camera.",
        Constants.PERMISSION_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE,
        permission.CAMERA
    )
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this)
}

override fun onPermissionsDenied(requestCode: Int, perms: List<String>) {
    speakOut("Permissions Denied.")

    if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionDenied(this, perms.first()))
        SettingsDialog.Builder(this).build()
            .show()  // If permissions are permanently denied show settings.
    else 
        requestCameraPermission()
}

override fun onPermissionsGranted(requestCode: Int, perms: List<String>) {
    cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        startCamera(cameraProviderFuture.get())
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))

    // Introduction
    val intro =
        "Welcome to Eyenetic. Please activate any module through voice command.The nodules are obstacle detection, scene recognition, currency detection, human object interaction and human human interaction."
    speakOut(intro)

    allButtons()
}
```

I only `addListener` to `cameraProviderFuture` when permission is granted. And when permission is granted i start the camera with no model running. Note when app is open each time no model will be running.

```
@SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
private fun startCamera(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider) {
    val preview = Preview.Builder().build()

    val cameraSelector =
        CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()

    preview.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)

    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)

}
```

And code for fetching `Object-Detection` model.

```
private fun readyObjectDetectionModel()
{
    val localModel = LocalModel.Builder().setAbsoluteFilePath("object_detection.tflite").build()
    val customObjectDetectionOptions = CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(localModel)
        .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.STREAM_MODE)
        .enableClassification()
        .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
        .build()

    objectDetector = ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectionOptions)
}
```

Code for `Object-Detection`

```
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
private fun startObjectDetection(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider) {
    val preview = Preview.Builder().build()

    val cameraSelector =
        CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()

    preview.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
    
    val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder().setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720))
        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST).build()

    imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
        {imageProxy ->
            val rotationDegrees =imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
            val image = imageProxy.image

            if (image != null) {
                val processImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(image, rotationDegrees)

                objectDetector.process(processImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        imageProxy.close()
                    }.addOnFailureListener{
                        imageProxy.close()
                    }
            }
    })
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis, preview)
}
```

I can run both codes for camera by calling each one at a time and commenting the other. But i have made different buttons to trigger different models. What should i do before calling each method.

> Right now the only way to i can think on is unbind the previous Life-cycle and make a new one. But what about the redundant code like

```
val preview = Preview.Builder().build()

val cameraSelector =
    CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()

preview.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)
```

> Is their way to only change the usecase on current bindedlifecycle?

> Should i make camerafragment and switch between different fragments?

> Any advice for better approaching this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One idea come to my mind is to create an [ImageAnalysis.Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis.Analyzer) subclass that can handle different ML features (in your word - ML models).

In that case, you only setup the imageAnalysis use case once, and the camera will keep feeding images to your Analyzer.

In your Analyzer, you can design some APIs like `switchTo(MLFeatureName name)`. When your UI button is pressed, you can call the switchTo method. After such a switch, the images will be fed to a different detector.

Make sure to close unused detector to release system resources.